# Is there a way to add a highlight color to the thumb border on lightslider?

Tags: jquery, css

Looking to add a border color to the thumb images..... Would I add it the the css or add a style section in the html code?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightslider.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content-slider").lightSlider({
            loop:true,
            keyPress:true
        });
        $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
            gallery:true,
            item:1,
            thumbItem:9,
            slideMargin: 0,
            speed:700,
            auto:true,
            loop:true,
            pause: 5500,
            bordercolor: #222222   <-------------------  ???
            onSliderLoad: function() {
                $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `lightSlider` [doesn't provide an option to style the border color](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html) of the images. You therefore cannot use `bordercolor` in the object.

You would need to use CSS like so:

```
.lSGallery > li {
    border: 1px solid #222222;
}
```

You can also target the current active thumbnail by doing:

```
.lSGallery > li.active {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: .lslide {
    border: 1px solid #222222;
}

Comment: .lslide {
    border: 1px solid #222222;
} adds a border color the the photo not the thumb

Comment: @DavidFunk: If that worked for you, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a CSS class either in HTML itself or in the external CSS file. make sure that the class you are writing is applied to all the elements. If you are still facing issues, please link a JSfiddle here so that we can have a better look into it.